# If there is no Data in the Production database can we restore it to Dr server

Tags: sql-server

I have a Production server and I restoring all databases to DR server. One database does not have the data and I am trying to restore it too, the restore job is running from past 24 hours.

- Can I run the restore successfully with out any issues?
- How can I go ahead with this restore?

Please let me know, I got tied up with this restore operation.

DB size in production is showing 7 MB.

Comment: Try running sp_WhoIsActive from http://whoisactive.com to see if someone is blocking your restore.

Comment: I will try and let you know , Thanks Brent I am a big fan Of you

Comment: sp_whoisactive @get_locks = 1 i have supplied this and i did not found any kind of locks for that DB..Kindly advice

Comment: As asked by @BrentOzar, is you restore session blocked?

Comment: I assume DR means Disaster Recovery.  I hope this is a test and not  live disaster.  I don't know what you mean "one database does not have the data" - did you perform your "restore all the databases" process, from the backups, and, there is this one database which hasn't been restored?

Comment: Dr Means Disaster Recovery , Session is not blocked. Other Databases are restored only DB is not restoring. thats the issue.